# Ansible VS BuiltTools 2022 With workloads

Tags: ansible, visual-studio-2022, chocolatey, build-tools, choco

I am using Ansible to install Visual Studio Build Tools 2022. I am trying to install specific workloads and using the documentation from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) , [ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/chocolatey/chocolatey/win_chocolatey_module.html) and [choco](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/visualstudio2022buildtools) but still not able to install the workloads I want with Ansible. I am new with Ansible so not sure what I am doing wrong.

My playbook run seems to complete with no issue, when I go to the server it is installing the visual studio installer is there but the workloads I need are not installed.

```
    - name: Install VS Tools
      win_chocolatey:
        name: visualstudio2022buildtools
        state: latest
        version: 117.9.0.0
        install_args:
          "--passive --wait ----includeOptional --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NodeBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.DataBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools"
      register: vs_output
```

output:

```
TASK [register for vs tools] ****************************************************************************
ok: [win_test] => {
"msg": " {'changed': False, 'rc': 0, 'choco_cli_version': '2.2.2', 
'failed': False}"
 }
```

Comment: Could you add the output value stored in `vs_output` to your question? Does it work if you run the corresponding command manually?

Comment: `'changed': False` means that Ansible didn't change anything on the target system because it's already in the desired state. You can try `force: true` to double check

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** I haven't directly tried the following, but I am basing this on how I believe the Visual Studio packages work.

The combination of Visual Studio Chocolatey packages rely on the usage of Package Parameters, or rather the `package_params` argument, rather than the Installation Arguemnts, or rather `install_args`, argument in your Ansible script.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/chocolatey/chocolatey/win_chocolatey_module.html#parameter-package_params

This can be seen in the example from taken from [here](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/visualstudio2022buildtools#description):

```
choco install visualstudio2022buildtools --package-parameters "--allWorkloads --includeRecommended --includeOptional --passive --locale en-US"
```

As such, I think the correct way of doing this would be:

```
    - name: Install VS Tools
      win_chocolatey:
        name: visualstudio2022buildtools
        state: present
        version: '117.9.0.0'
        package_params:
          "--includeOptional --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NodeBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.DataBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools"
      register: vs_output
```

Also, based on this (taken from [here](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/visualstudio2022buildtools#description)):

> The package passes --norestart --wait by default, and --quiet, unless --passive is specified in the package parameters.

You may want to re-think your usage of the `--wait` and `--passive` arguments that you were attempting to pass in.

Comment: I would also add that it's recommended to quote the version to avoid the transformation of dots to commas due to the possible locale differences.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev I have updated the answer with this suggestion, as well as to change from latest to present for the state of the package.

Comment: unfortunately that did not work. I got it to work by calling the workloads individually.

Answer (score 0):

An improved version of [@PanzerRage's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78108833/16417367) - I don't see it on the module documentation page, but usually for package management modules it's recommended to pass the list of packages directly to the `name` instead of running the module in a loop due to performance reasons:

```yaml
- name: Install Visual Studio Build Tools
  win_chocolatey:
    name: visualstudio2022buildtools
    state: latest
    version: "117.9.0.0"

- name: Install specific workloads
  win_chocolatey:
    name:
      - visualstudio2022-workload-nodebuildtools
      - visualstudio2022-workload-webbuildtools
      - visualstudio2022-workload-databuildtools
    state: latest
```

Answer (score -1):

Got it to work by installing the workloads individually:

```
 - name: Install Visual Studio Build Tools
   win_chocolatey:
    name: visualstudio2022buildtools
    state: latest
    version: "117.9.0.0"

- name: Install specific workloads
  win_chocolatey:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: latest
  loop:
    - visualstudio2022-workload-nodebuildtools
    - visualstudio2022-workload-webbuildtools
    - visualstudio2022-workload-databuildtools
```

Comment: Running a package management module in a loop is usually much slower than passing the list to `name`. I added an answer addressing that.